# Bitmap to texture

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, bitmap

I have to convert bitmap image to texture format. And need to display it . For this I have written a function to convert bit map to texture . But when running the code it shows a blank image without any crashes. Please help to identify

In privew.java , I have created a bitmap object for an image (inside resource folder )in onCreate() function.

```
//Creating a sample image's resource id for testing in GlRenderer
    drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("flower", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
    System.out.println("FLOWER ID "+drawableResourceId);
    InputStream is =this.getResources().openRawResource(drawableResourceId);
    Bitmap tBitmap;
    tBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, sBitmapOptions);
    ThisAppGlobals.texture_bitmap=tBitmap;
```

And in GlRenderer.java (Renderer class for OpenGl) used a function named "loadGLTextureFromBitmap()" to create texture for corresponding bitmap object . 
I'am called that function onSurfaceCreated() of openGl class .

```
  // setup texture //
       int mTextureID
       System.out.println("Calling loadGLTextureFromBitmap");
       mTextureID = loadGLTextureFromBitmap(ThisAppGlobals.texture_bitmap, gl );
       System.out.println("Called loadGLTextureFromBitmap"+  mTextureID);
```

And the function is ,

```
    private int loadGLTextureFromBitmap(Bitmap sideBysideImg, GL10 gl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    // Generate one texture pointer
    int[] textureIds = new int[1];
    gl.glGenTextures( 1, textureIds, 0 );

    // bind this texture
    gl.glBindTexture( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIds[0] );

    // Create Nearest Filtered Texture
    gl.glTexParameterf( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR );
    gl.glTexParameterf( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR );

    gl.glTexParameterf( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT );
    gl.glTexParameterf( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT );

    // Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
    GLUtils.texImage2D( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,sideBysideImg, 0 );
    return textureIds[0];


}
```

And onSurfaceChanged() consists

```
GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
       checkGlError("glBindTexture mTextureID");

       GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                           GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
       GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                           GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

       /*
        * Create the SurfaceTexture that will feed this textureID,
        * and pass it to the MediaPlayer
        */
       mSurface = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureID);
       mSurface.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

     Surface surface = new Surface(mSurface);
             surface.release();
```

Comment: Why you are not using base64 format to convert bitmap?

Comment: I didn't get what you meant .Can you please share me an example ? I'am beginner to android . that's why . Any help would be appreciated

Comment: do you call gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); before rendering?

Comment: @samgak  No,  I  didn't used it . Where should I add this line (OnSurfaceChanged /OnsurfaceCreated/OnDraw) ?

Comment: @samgak I have tried as you suggested . but shows same issue.  Do you have any helpful  link to solve this ?

Comment: try this tutorial http://www.jayway.com/2010/12/30/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-vi-textures/

Comment: What's the size of the bitmap/texture? You may want to try `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` instead of `GL_REPEAT` for the wrap modes.